# Debian jessie 8 clean installation

Tags: linux, debian, apt, package-management

I've installed debian jessie from net iso (~240Mb). On the last installation wizard step, i've unchecked all checkboxes (no kde, web, mysql, and system utilities also).

Well right after that "apt-get update" won't work and requires package named:
apt-transport-https.

But when tryin to install got the same error. Going through sources.list file, but there are http links everywhere (not https).

Is there any chance to install this package?

Comment: Perhaps best to report a bug against the meta-package "debian-installer"?

Comment: Odd. I have several Jessie boxes w/o apt-transport-https installed, and am not seeing problems. Which mirrors are in your `sources.list`? Does `apt-get update --print-uris | grep https` give anything?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any chance to install this package?

There is *always* a chance to install the package. At worst, you can go find it on http://packages.debian.org/ and download it and install it with `dpkg -i`.

I don't know why you got this problem though. As you said, all of the sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list` are http, not https. Did you check `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` also? But you probably won't find anything there.

I installed a new Debian jessie system using the latest jessie installer last Thursday and did not have any problem like that. In the tasksel dialog I selected "SSH server" and "standard system utilities" (paraphrasing from memory) and nothing else — which was actually the default.

Comment: sources.list.d is empty. Well i missed all the checkmarks including ssh server and ssu. That's a reason I've registered and wrote. Seems strange that cache is built on https links and package apt-transport-https is missing by default. Wheezy wont come with such problem.

Comment: @Ruberoid wait, cache? Are you using a proxy (webcache) which is over https:// ?

Comment: @derobert, Ohh thank you, that was a key. Unfortunately i met https proxy.

Comment: @Ruberoid it sounds like you've indeed found a bug: if you configure an https proxy in the installer, it really ought to install apt-transport-https. I guess you've found it doesn't. I suggest reporting the bug to Debian. You can get your system working, as Celada suggests, by manually downloading that package and installing with `dpkg -i`.